# How to fix "Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'"

Tags: javascript, angular, server

Error:SchemaValidationException [Error]: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.
errors: [
{
instancePath: '',
schemaPath: '#/required',
keyword: 'required',
params: { missingProperty: 'browserTarget' },
message: "must have required property 'browserTarget'"
}
]
}

Angular.json  `"@angular/animations": "^15.0.0", "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.2", "@angular/common": "^15.0.0", "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0", "@angular/core": "^15.0.0", "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0", "@angular/material": "^15.0.3", "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0", "@angular/router": "^15.0.0", "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0", "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1", "angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks": "^15.0.1", "bootstrap": "^5.2.3", "rxjs": "~7.5.0", "tslib": "^2.3.0", "zone.js": "~0.12.0"`

I did try run

```
ng serve
```

I tried to change the version of angular, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hi, please format your code. You can find help here: [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)